# Arbitrary Non-linear colorbar depicting periodic function in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to generate a `pcolormesh` where the color gradient will vary depending upon a non-linear periodic function such as `abs` of cos. A custom 
normalization should suffice. So far I tried the code below:

```
class XNormalize(mcolors.Normalize):
    def __call__(self, value, clip=None):
        return np.ma.masked_array(np.abs(np.cos(value)))
```

I am not sure apply `self.vmin`, `self.vmax` mapping in this case since the `cos` can virtually take any input.

The code to generate output:

```
inner_azimuths = np.arange(0, 361, 1)
inner_zeniths = np.arange(50, 55, 1)
inner_values = inner_azimuths * np.ones((5, 361))
fig = plt.figure(tight_layout=True)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar=True)
ax.pcolormesh((inner_azimuths)*np.pi/180.0, inner_zeniths, inner_values, cmap='jet_r', zorder=2, antialiased=True, norm=XNormalize(vmin=0, vmax=2*np.pi))
```

The output currently looks like the follows:

[image: Current plot]

I also tried the following function:

```
def distortColorMap(cm,inv = lambda x:x):
    """Inspired from 'make_colormap' in Serenity's answer.

    Inputs : a pre-existing colormap cm, 
            the distorsion function inv

    Output : the distorted colormap"""

    def f(color,inv):
        """In the sequence definition, modifies the position of stops tup[0] according the transformation function.

        Returns the distorted sequence."""
        return map(lambda tup:(inv(tup[0]),tup[1],tup[2]),color)

    # Extract sequences from cm, apply inv
    C = cm.__dict__['_segmentdata']
    cdict = {'red': f(C['red']  ,inv), 'green': f(C['green'],inv), 'blue': f(C['blue'] ,inv)}

    name = 'new_'+cm.__dict__['name']
    return colors.LinearSegmentedColormap(name, cdict)
```

Bit it did not work as well.

Sources: [(a)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46059318/6422069), [(b)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46052127/6422069)

Comment: I don't think it's clear what exactly does not work here. To me the code seems fine. In how far is the output not expected?

Comment: I want a smooth gradient radially between two angles, not a repeating fringe. For example, when I use default linear normalization the output is like: ![Smooth Plot](https://i.imgur.com/0sWDrQm.png)

Comment: Isn't that a question of input data? Currently your values range from 0 to 360. That would correspont to roughly 60 periods of the cosine, or 120 periods of the absolute cosine. That's close to what you see in the plot.

Comment: Inner_values needs to be in radians (or you need to change your Norm to work with radians)

Comment: I knew that the `values` have to be passed as radians. So, I converted the values to radian manually by doing `(inner_azimuths)*np.pi/180.0`, somehow it did not work. Now, It works when I pass `np.deg2rad(inner_azimuths)` instead. Finally solved. Thanks.